# skipping database records if count is 0

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, count

I have a query that

```
 select count(api_name),api_name from abc_log where id = '1'
 group by api_name
```

its fine and i am getting correct result .

Suppose my output is

```
 count       api_name

   1          abc
   10         123
   12         aaa
   0          xxx
```

but i do n't need to get apinames which are having count '0'

How i need to write query?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's no possible because is no api_name you have no row

Comment: Your query is correct, your output is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the condition for filtering out the count(api_name) = 0

```
select count(api_name),api_name from abc_log where id = '1'
 group by api_name 
having count(api_name) <> 0
```

Comment: is api_name = 0 no row returns.

Comment: @JoeTaras you are correct. Its not a possible to have an output which is having zero count

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **having** clause, like this:

```
select count(api_name),api_name from abc_log where id = '1'
group by api_name 
having count(api_name) > 0
```

If you meant you wanted the name blanked out on 0, then try this query:

```
select count(api_name) count, 
  CASE count WHEN >0 THEN api_name ELSE ' ' END
from abc_log 
where id = '1'
group by api_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `api_name` has `null` value, then you can just filtered out it :

```
select count(api_name), api_name 
from abc_log 
where id = 1 and api_name is not null
group by api_name;
```

If the `id` has numeric type, then you don't need to use single quote.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider the following:

```
with T as (
    select count(api_name) count, api_name
    from abc_log
    where id = '1'
    group by api_name
)
select *
from T
where count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(api_name),api_name from abc_log where id = '1'
 group by api_name 
having count(api_name) > 0
```

Give it a try. The query by George will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select count(api_name), api_name 
from abc_log
where id = 1  -- guessing that id is a number
group by api_name ;
```

could *only* return `0` for the count when `api_name` is `NULL`.  It would not occur for an "xxx" value.

My guess is that your query is more complicated.

For this query, I would recommend:

```
select count(api_name), api_name 
from abc_log
where id = 1 and -- guessing that id is a number
      api_name is not null
group by api_name ;
```

The more general solution is to use `having` (which others have answered):

```
select count(api_name), api_name 
from abc_log
where id = 1 and -- guessing that id is a number
      api_name is not null
group by api_name
having count(api_name) > 0 ;
```

However, it is better (from a performance and clarity perspective) to filter before the aggregation.